# round up decimal values to exact integer value php

Tags: php, rounding

I have came across the php rounding decimal values by using:
The **round()** function rounds a floating-point number.
To round a number *UP* to the nearest integer, look at the **ceil()** function.
To round a number *DOWN* to the nearest integer, look at the **floor()** function.

I have an example of dividing 1000/13 which when we use
**round(1000/13, 2)** will give you 999.98 and then i will use **ceil** to round it to 1000.
Now, my value is 925.6 which has to be divided by 11 and I tried with the 
**round(925.6/11, 2)** which will give 84.15, then if u multiply this with 11(84.15 * 11)then you will get **925.56**. Now how can achieve the exact decimal if any decimal input.

Comment: If you're already rounding it off in the first place, you can't expect to get the same result after multiplying. That's basic Math. Not sure what exactly you're up to.

Comment: im doing these for the monthly generated contract bills, you would know that the decimal values plays a role in payment transactions.

Answer (score 1):

> Rounding-off a Double or Float using `round()`, `ceil()` or `floor()` all have one thing in Common and that is: by using them you are subscribing to losing the Precision of your Data. This means; once the die is cast, you cannot get the Original value again.... it is that simple:

If you want to retain both the Truncated and the Original Values, you have to do it differently.... You may need to keep 2 Variables or simply put your Variables in an Array. A Simple example would demonstrate this even better:

```
<?php

        $num        = (925.6/11);

        // STORE THE ORIGINAL & ROUNDED VALUES IN AN ARRAY (IN CASE YOU NEED BOTH)
        $arrNumbers = [
                'original'  =>  $num,
                'rounded'   =>  round($num, 2),
        ];

        // NOW; FOR YOUR MULTIPLICATIONS:
        $original   = $arrNumbers['original'] * 11;
        $broken     = $arrNumbers['rounded']  * 11;


        var_dump($original);    //<== float 925.6
        var_dump($broken);      //<== float 925.65    :: ADDED AN EXTRA 0.05 (BOGUS, HUH?)
        var_dump($arrNumbers);  //<== array (size=2) 'original' => float 84.1454545455  'rounded' => float 84.15
```

**UPDATE: NUMERATOR AS A VALUE FROM FORM-FIELD.**

```
     <?php

        // ASSUME THE VALUE OF THE NUMERATOR IS: 925.6
        $numerator      = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['some_field'])); 

        // AND THE DENOMINATOR IS NOW SOMETHING LIKE MONTH 11 AS IN: 11.0000
        $denominator    = 11.0000;                                           

        // NO PROBLEMS STILL...
        $num            = ($numerator/$denominator);

        // STORE THE ORIGINAL & ROUNDED VALUES IN AN ARRAY (IN CASE YOU NEED BOTH)
        $arrNumbers     = [
                'original'  =>  $num,
                'rounded'   =>  round($num, 2),
        ];

        // NOW; FOR YOUR MULTIPLICATION,
        // TO GET THE STARTING VALUES BACK DO:
        $original       = $arrNumbers['original'] * 11;
        $broken         = $arrNumbers['rounded']  * 11;


        var_dump($original);    //<== float 925.6
        var_dump($broken);      //<== float 925.65    :: ADDED AN EXTRA 0.05 (BOGUS, HUH?)
        var_dump($arrNumbers);  //<== array (size=2) 'original' => float 84.1454545455  'rounded' => float 84.15
```

Comment: the numerator comes from a form and the denominator is the no. of months so it can change to any decimal points, so does this work with such kind.

Comment: this rounded value 84.15 has to go in a for loop as per the $denominator. so can u put these inside a for loop.

Comment: 925.6 is a 11-months paying amount, so we have to take the no.of months into a for loop and put this value for a monthly basis. check my command above, below my question where I said why am I trying these things. Next to the  @Object Manipulator

Comment: @learner     Saw and got the comment  but would you mind going to http://eval.in and writing any Psuedo-Code to demonstrate (however vaguely) how you intend the loop to be used in this regard? Afterwards, you may copy the Link from http://eval.in and paste it here as a comment so one can clearly picture what you meant.... (if that is ok with you)

Comment: yes, i will do. But it a lot of code if you want. I'm doing it now. here is my link
https://eval.in/650568

Comment: @learner   if You meant this Loop: `for($i=0; $i<$no_of_records; $i++) {$calculated_records     = intval($i * $billing_cycle_division);$contract_date          = strtotime("+".$calculated_records." months", $contract_start_date);echo date('Y-m-t',$contract_date)." Value for a month is: ". $contract_value ."<br />";if($contract_date > $contract_end_date) { break; }}`   
 ; then YES — You can still use it within that loop. You just have to declare it at the top of the script as it was done here in this post.

Comment: yes, that's the one and if u got any idea on rewritting the whole into a better one, please give a suggestion to how to do it. And can u just provide a link in eval.in for inside the for loop